# cannot useradd/adduser when /etc/{passwd,shadow,group} are symlink (debian squeeze)

Tags: debian

i'm having trouble with useradd
when im moving 
    /etc/passwd
    /etc/shadow
    /etc/group
from /etc to /home and create a symlink in order to have /etc/{passwd,shadow,group} respecively pointing to /home/{passwd,shadow,group}

i cannot create any user and have useradd outputing:

```
root@client:/home# useradd testuser
Adding user `testuser' ...
Adding new group `testuser' (1000) ...
groupadd: cannot open /etc/group
```

btw useradd output is

```
root@client:/home# adduser testuser
useradd: cannot open /etc/passwd
```

Comment: I'm not surprised; the locations and nature of `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` in particular are very long-standing UNIX concepts.  Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: Agreed - this is a **very** bad idea.

Comment: for testing purposes

Comment: If `/etc` and `/home` reside in the same filesystem, you could use hardlinks (`ln` without the `-s` option).

Comment: That's a  vague response... I'm afraid you're still stuck with "don't do this".

Comment: ln -P aint working cause /home is an nfs mounting point

Comment: Tell us what you're trying to achieve, there is almost certainly a better way to do whatever it is.

Comment: +1 for experimenting (I hope that wasn't a productive server!) and daring to ask.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Why does `useradd` refuse to open a symlinked `/etc/passwd`?

To answer the question we need to take a look at the source code of `useradd` (I did this on Ubuntu 12.04, on Debian it may differ slightly):

1. Find out which package owns `/usr/sbin/useradd`:

   ```
   $ dpkg-query -S /usr/sbin/useradd
   passwd: /usr/sbin/useradd
   ```
2. Install the source:

   ```
   $ apt-get source passwd
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   Picking 'shadow' as source package instead of 'passwd'
   (...)
   dpkg-source: info: extracting shadow in shadow-4.1.4.2+svn3283
   dpkg-source: info: unpacking shadow_4.1.4.2+svn3283.orig.tar.gz
   dpkg-source: info: applying shadow_4.1.4.2+svn3283-3ubuntu5.1.diff.gz
   (...)
   ```
3. `cd` to the source directory:

   ```
   $ cd shadow-4.1.4.2+svn3283/
   ```
4. Search the directory for `useradd`'s source file, which ideally should be called `useradd.c`:

   ```
   $ find . -name useradd.c
   ./src/useradd.c
   ```

   Bingo!
5. Look for error message `cannot open /etc/passwd` (in fact I only search for `cannot open`, since the whole string doesn't return any results):

   ```
   $ grep -B 1 'cannot open' src/useradd.c
   (...)
     if (pw_open (O_RDWR) == 0) {
         fprintf (stderr, _("%s: cannot open %s\n"), Prog, pw_dbname ());
   (...)
   ```

   `-B 1` means print 1 line of leading context before the matching line.

   This is where the error message you see is being generated. Function `pw_open` controls whether `/etc/passwd` can be opened or an error should be thrown.

   `pw_open` is not a Linux [syscall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (`apropos pw_open` doesn't return any results), so it is probably implemented within this package. Let's search for it.
6. Tracing `pw_open` leads to:

   ```
   $ grep -R pw_open * 
   (...)
   lib/pwio.c:int pw_open (int mode)
   (...)
   ```

   `pw_open` implementation is:

   ```
   $ grep -A 3 'int pw_open (int mode)' lib/pwio.c 
   int pw_open (int mode)
   {
       return commonio_open (&passwd_db, mode);
   }
   ```

   Getting closer, but we're not there yet. `commonio_open` is our new objective.
7. Search for `commonio_open`:

   ```
   $ grep -R commonio_open *
   (...)
   lib/commonio.c:int commonio_open (struct commonio_db *db, int mode)
   ```
8. Open `lib/commonio.c` and scroll to function `commonio_open`:

   ```
   int commonio_open (struct commonio_db *db, int mode)
   {
   (...)

       fd = open (db->filename,
                    (db->readonly ? O_RDONLY : O_RDWR)
                  | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK | O_NOFOLLOW);
   ```

   Do you see `O_NOFOLLOW`? This is the culprit (from `man 2 open`):

   ```
   O_NOFOLLOW 
         If pathname is a symbolic link, then the open fails.
   ```

**Summarizing, `useradd.c` uses `pw_open`, which in turn uses `commonio_open`, which opens `/etc/passwd` using syscall `open` with option `O_NOFOLLOW`, that rejects symbolic links.**

Although a symlink can be used as a replacement of a file in many (I'd say most) situations, `useradd` is quite picky and rejects it, probably because a symlinked `/etc/passwd` strongly suggests that `/etc` has been tampered with.

### Why should I leave `passwd` in `/etc`?

There are several files in `/etc` needed to boot and log in, for example (but not limited to): `fstab`, `inittab`, `passwd`, `shadow` and the init scripts in `init.d/`. Any sysadmin expects those files to be there, not symlinked to `/home` or wherever.

So even if you could, you should leave `passwd` in `/etc`.

Furthermore, the filesystem structure in Linux is well defined, take a look at it here: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html. There is also a chapter for [`/etc`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#ETCHOSTSPECIFICSYSTEMCONFIGURATION). Moving things around is not recommended.

Comment: What a beautifully-presented and well-researched answer.  I'd give it +10 if I could.

Comment: @jaume - Awesome!

Comment: Sorry for this late answer


On debian useradd uses open (2)

With strace we can see that write(2) on passwd fail because open(2) has O_NOFOLLOW flag and returned -1

you were right!

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad I could help. I also used `strace` but somehow I didn't manage to find the relevant line, it's great you did!

Comment: Interestingly, the [reference](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#ETCHOSTSPECIFICSYSTEMCONFIGURATION) lists `passwd` and `group` below the header "The following files, or symbolic links to files, must be in `/etc`"

Comment: Amazing thorough investigation 

Answer (score 2):

> *Doctor, it hurts when I do this.*

⁠

> *Well, don't do it then!*

Seriously, don't stick files as critical as that in an unexpected location. Whatever you're trying to test: find a better way. If you're trying to do central authentication: use ldap. Or nis if you must.

Comment: i'll take a look at ldap and nis

Comment: If I were the doctor I'd say 'Let me take a look!'. My diagnosis (and recommendation) is in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

System unable to make any changes on the files /etc/passwd, /etc/shadow

Regenerate issue:

```
[root@ubuntu]# useradd salten
cannot open /etc/passwd
useradd: cannot open /etc/group
useradd: cannot open /etc/gshadow
```

Below shows that files are immutable, If you set the `-i` argument, a file will be marked as "immutable", meaning its data (and some vital metadata) cannot be changed, even by root, until the attribute is unset.

List the attributes:

```
[root@salten]#lsattr /etc/passwd
----i-------- /etc/shadow
```

Change the file attribute :

```
[root@salten]# chattr -i /etc/passwd
[root@salten]# lsattr /etc/passwd
[root@salten]# chattr -i /etc/group
[root@salten]# chattr -i /etc/gshadow
```

Try to add user:

```
[root@salten]# useradd apache
```

It works !!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).